# How to detect button background resource (drawable) android?

Tags: android, drawable, ontouchlistener, mediarecorder

I am currently building an app that has a button that once the user clicks the button, media recorder is initiated and records for five seconds and then stops. This recording is then loaded into media player which the user can then playback by pressing the button once again. Here is my code so far:

```
    OUTPUT_FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tempRecord.3gpp";
    audioSample1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sample1);
    // button background drawable is grey_button
    final Drawable buttonBackground = audioSample1.getBackground();     
    audioSample1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (audioSample1.getBackground().equals(buttonBackground)) {
                Log.d("Button", "Start Record");
                try {
                    startRecord();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else if (audioSample1.getBackground() != null) {
                Log.d("Button", "Start Playback");
                try {
                    startPlayback();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

public void startRecord() throws Exception {
    if (recorder != null) {
        recorder.release();
    }
    File fileOut = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
    if (fileOut != null) {
        fileOut.delete();
    }
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(5000);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
    audioSample1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {

        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder recorder, int timer, int extra) {
            if (timer == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                Log.v("Recorder", "Maximum Duration Reached");
                recorder.stop();
                audioSample1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_button);    
            }
        }
    });
}

public void startPlayback() throws Exception {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}

Basically the issue I am having is the `onClick` method detects the state of the button and depending on the background drawable it either start recording or starts playback. If the button is in its first state `drawable.grey_button` the media recorder will start recording and change the background drawable to a red_button and once it is finished recording it will change to a green_button for playback. This code works fine generally but if the user presses the button while the media recorder is recording the media player will be unable to create a media player. I know the problem is because I am calling `audioSample1.getBackground() != null` but I can't figure out any other way to detect the `backgroundResources` that has been changed

Please can someone give me some advice on how to detect each `backgroundResource`?

Also once the Media Player is loaded with a audio sample I now want the same button to be able to implement an `onTouchListener` and gesture detector. Is this possible and how do you implement such a method?

Thanks

Comment: Darren was it helpful? let me know

Comment: My apologises @Elitz I thought I had marked this as the correct answer already. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you approach is really tedious, but this is it <strike>`getBackgroundDrawable();`</strike> use this instead `getBackground()` **Returns the drawable set for the button.**

but you can also use the string for the button, that might be simple...

**EDIT 1** *this approach is better*

```
  Button b = new Button(this); // now this is your button
    b.setText("Play"); //the button has a name as 'play' when its not clicked 
    // and in your case is drawable.grey_button
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_button);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {//setting your onclick

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Button bb = (Button) arg0; // getting your clicked button
            if(bb.getText().toString().equals("play")){ // checking if the text on your bb is play
                //start your playback and change the background
                bb.setText("pause"); // setting the text to pause
            }else if(bb.getText().toString().equals("pause")){
                //pause playback and change your background
                bb.setText("play");
            }else{
                //stop play and reset mediaplayer and change your background.. 
                // this is not even captured
            }

        }
    });
```

this approach is better.. let me know if it helps

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. It won't detect the drawable background. Sorry I am pretty new to Android. Can you explain it a little clearer please? When you say I am approaching it really tediously could you recommend a different way for the button to detect the different states?

Comment: this approach returns the drawable used as the background for this view, if any.-using `setBackground()` so check it gives you a drawable..ok about the approach wait..@Darren